# Producing Single Item and Moving Counter Forward

Tags: c#, dictionary, yield, consumer, producer

I'm working on a problem where I need to provide one item at a time to the consumer and move the counter forward so next item and so on until ran out of items. I came up with first draft of code (see below). The underlying data structure contains a Dictionary which contains string as its key and hold another dictionary as its value, which holds object of type Entity.

I've a sense that I do need to maintain the state somehow, so I tried using yield return statement but not sure how to jell it together. Also I think using forearch/iterator may need adjustment since consumer will call GetNextItem() until it returns false(meaning run out of items).

```
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary <uint,Entity>> dt;   
private uint localCounter=0 , globalCounter = 0;

public Entity GetNextItem()
{
    foreach (string key in dt.Keys )
    {
        if (MoveCounters(key)) //counter is moved, so process the next item
        {
            yield return dt[key][localCounter];
        }
    }

}

private bool MoveCounters(string key)
{
    if (++globalCounter > dt.Count) return false; //hit the limit
    if (++localCounter >  dt[key].Count)
    {
        globalCounter++;
        return true;
    }

    localCounter++;
    return true;
   }
}


public class Entity
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dtValues; //contains values from CSV file.
}
```

Comment: where are you adding the keys to the Dictionary..? could you not do this `yield return dt.Add(dt[key][localCounter]);` something like that..?

Comment: Keys will be added separately, its like two pass system. First pass fill the dictionary and then producer can serve it once its filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're failing to reset `localCounter` to zero when you move to the next sublist.

That said, you can do this so much easier:

```
foreach (var subdt in dt.Values)
   foreach (var item in subdt.Values)
       yield return item;
```

But it's even easier using LINQ `SelectMany`

```
return dt.Values.SelectMany(subdt => subdt.Values);
```

Note that the last one does not use `yield return`, since LINQ produces the enumerable and you just return it.

If you want to log the keys and counters as well, try something like:

```
int iList = 0;
foreach( var subdt in dt ) {
    /* log iList, subdt.Key */
    int iItem = 0;
    foreach( var item in subdt.Value ) {
       /* log iItem, item.Key */
       ++iItem;
       yield return item.Value;
    }
    ++iList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like to know in case of yield can I track which items been processed? With counters I always know that by looking at values of both of the counters. I'm thinking maintaining a list and putting some sort of value in it to keep track of that and use it just before yield return statement.

Comment: @user: You can definitely use counters inside the foreach loops, or use keys, or KeyValuePair objects.  I'll add an example.  The big improvement is letting `foreach` find the end of each sublist for you.